# IE 8 - HttpResponse - Can't display PDF

Tags: asp.net, httpresponse

I am getting one weird issue with IE 8 only. In my app, we have write the binary response to the HttpResponse object and the data content is PDF. We are using third part tool "Tall PDF" to make PDF's. But this whole operation end up in freezing my IE and eventually had to end-task the IE instance..

Following is the code excerpts:-

```
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            nb.WritePDF(Response);    
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
```

nb is the class and calling the method WritePDF to write the data to the Response obj. This thing is working fine in IE 7 and other browsers, but for some reason it is giving problem in IE8.

Pls suggest any work arounds or tweaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution

```
response.AddHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=EmulateIE7");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code snippet provided in the following blog post: [Rendering PDF Files to Browser using .NET Code](http://mshahzadlatif.wordpress.com/2011/08/24/rendering-pdf-files-to-browser-using-net-code/)